# Software/library to compute order of element in a group

Tags: math-software

I need a software/library where I can define an arbitrary multiplicative group of integers modulo n (with large n), input an element, and obtain the order of that element in the group as output.

Answer (score 1):

The programming language [GAP](https://www.gap-system.org/) ("Groups, Algorithms, Programming") is very good when working with groups.